# Cannot set property 'user' of undefined

Tags: typescript, callback

I am finding it difficult to set a property value inside callback function.
Here is the component class :

```
export class HomeComponent{
 user : any;
constructor(){
let userId = localStorage.getItem('id');
        console.log(userId);
        this.getUserDetailsById(userId,function(result){
            console.log(result);
            this.user = result;
        });
}



getUserDetailsById(id:any,callback){
        this.userService.getUserDetailsById(id).subscribe(user => {
            callback(user);
        })
    }
}
```

I am trying to set `user` to return value of `getUserDetailsById()` and using the `user` to two-way data binding on ui. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to follow ES6 coding pattern ;
`this` is not accessible inside `getUserDetailsById()` use arrow function like

```
constructor(){
let userId = localStorage.getItem('id');
        console.log(userId);
        this.getUserDetailsById(userId,(result) =>{
            console.log(result);
            this.user = result;
        });
}
```

update your constructor.

Comment: It works. But I dont understand it, why `this` works different in `function()` and arrow function?

Comment: look at this  [link[(https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/)